# how to insert array values in a table in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I'm trying to insert array values into the table:

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE  "KABIL_PRACTICE"."Array_Insert"
(
"Id" integer,
"Dept_Id" integer array
);

INSERT INTO "KABIL_PRACTICE"."Array_Insert" VALUES( 3, array
(2,3,5,6));
```

But it results looks like:

| Id | Dept_Id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 040000000102000000010300000001050000000106000000 |

I can't understand what is the meaning of above values in "Dept_Id" column...

but I want to see my table original values like:

| Id | Dept_Id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |
| ? | 3 |
| ? | 5 |
| ? | 6 |

Comment: You should not define "Dept_Id" as an array then. The value `040000...000` is the internal representation of `array(2,3,5,6)`, `04000000` meaning an array of 4 entries, I don't know for `01` repeated in front of each value `02000000` (2), `03000000` (3), etc. For the rest, see Lars answer.

Answer (score 1):

The topic of "array"-insert in SAP HANA has been extensively discussed here on SO. Please do the search for yourself on that.

However, your expected result rather looks as if you want to perform a **bulk** insert of many records.
That's different to an ARRAY insert, where the array is the value of one of the columns for a single record.

If you actually have multiple records to deal with (e.g. in a JAVA array or collection), then what you can do is to loop over all elements and add them one by one to a single **bulk** statement (aka **batch** statement).